# Weighted percentage contribution by row in R

Tags: r, percentage, weighted-average, rowsum

I have a matrix of 2 columns. I calculated the percentage contribution of each column by row to the overall using the formula below:

```
B = matrix (c(2,4,3,1,5,7,5,3,8,3,7,3),nrow=6,ncol=2) 
sweep(B, 1, rowSums(B), FUN="/")
```

This gives the result below:

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.2857143 0.7142857
[2,] 0.5714286 0.4285714
[3,] 0.2727273 0.7272727
[4,] 0.2500000 0.7500000
[5,] 0.4166667 0.5833333
[6,] 0.7000000 0.3000000
```

However, I need to add weights to each row i.e. 1 for row 1 and 3 for row 2. How do I compute the weighted percentage contribution, please?

Comment: `I need to add weights to each row` What weights? You only mention row 1 & 2. What is the expected output?

Comment: I added "1 and 3" i.e. If I had 10 and 4 and wanted to add these weights, it will be ((10*1) + (4*3))/4 which will be 4. The weights I want to add are "1" for the first row and "2" for the second row.

Comment: Unclear, please provide expected output.